# create field in view other than database fiels

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i want to add one field in view from my module.Is there any way to add a field which is not in database to the drupal view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a computed field (http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to your nodes? This doesn't have to be stored in the database and it could use your module, or you could enter php code directly.